# Understand and convert query to Oracle SQL

Tags: php, oracle, plsql

I am a little bit confusing and I am totally nOoB in `PHP` and I stuck in one `query` which made me problem.

```
 $sql = "UPDATE student SET Status = $stuStatus".($status === 'success-student' ? ', Marks = 2' : '')." WHERE StudentId = {$data['studentID']};";
```

If I would like transform this to Oracle SQL Is is something like this

```
UPDATE student SET Status = status (SELECT CASE WHEN status = 'success-student' THEN Mark = 2) WHERE StudentId = $studentId
```

Comment: I would not post question here If I know what does it mean :D That why I asking question If someone could explain me what does this mean and how to convert it to `Oracle SQL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following:

```php
$sql = "UPDATE student SET Status =". $stuStatus ." ,  Marks =" . ($status === 'success-student' ? '2' : '') . " WHERE StudentId = " . $data['studentID'] . ";";
```

It should produce an SQL query as follow, which will put the mark 2 if the student status equals `success-student`.

```sql
/*
 example: 
   $stuStatus = 'success'
   $status = 'success-student'
   $data['studentID'] = 1 
*/

UPDATE student SET Status = 'success', Marks = 2 WHERE StudentId = 1;
```

Comment: Isn't this part 
`$stuStatus".($status === 'success-student' ? ', Marks = 2' : '')." ` 
Something like 
`If (stuStatus = 'success' OR Marka = 2) THEN `
`do something`

Comment: ($status === 'success-student' ? ', Marks = 2' : '') is an inline IF expression ( [link](https://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators) ) in PHP. While the `IF-THEN-ENDIF`  is PL/SQL.